# Exchange 2010 CAS and Edge-Transport on VPS in datacentres

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I have a central office site and I would like to know if it is considered acceptable to install Exchange 2010 CAS/Edge-Transport roles on VPS(s) in external datacentre(s) with a VPN back to our HQ where our mailbox and hub servers are.

My main goal is to have mail queued should the main site go down due to a local ISP failure.

Would there be any issues with this design and anything to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ***SMTP-Backup providers*** out there. Use one of these if you only want to "queue" mails.

If you want to pursue your idea of an *own* server/VPS, then just use the ***EDGE-Transport*** role on the VPS, and not CAS, as CAS will not work anyway if it has no connection to the Mailbox server.